# python join 2 files and write into new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement like below:

input1_txt

```
a
b
c
```

input2_txt

```
1|2|3|a|e|f
1|3|4|b|g|h
3|2|4|c|f|h
d|f|g|i|h|j
```

I am trying to read both input1,input2 and writing into ouput_file

if input1 first column is equal to input2 fouth column
then write all input2 to ouput_file.

Code:

```
read1 = csv.reader(open(input1_txt, 'r')) # read input file 1
write = csv.writer(open(output_file,"w"), delimiter="|", lineterminator="\n")  
 

for row1 in read1:
    #print(row1)
    read2 = csv.reader(open(input2_file, 'r'), delimiter="|", lineterminator="\n")
    for row2 in read2:
        #print(row2)
        if row1 == row2[4]:
            write.writerows(row2)
```

The expected output is as below: i..e only matched input1 first column and input2 fouth column

```
                  1|2|3|a|e|f
                  1|3|4|b|g|h
                  3|2|4|c|f|h
```

This code show how not getting any results.Please advise.

Comment: maybe first read all to memory and later use it. Reading again and again the same file in loop can be slow.

Comment: what is the expected output file? your description isn't clear

Comment: you should convert first file to list `["a", "b", "c"]` and then you can check `if row[4] in ["a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: You can't read the same file multiple times. Read the fields into a list, and then loop over that list as many times as you like. (Except, don't loop. Read them into a set and simply check if the fourth field is in that set.)

Comment: Have updated the expected output

Comment: if you reall want to use two `for`-loops then you should use `for row1` inside `for row2`

Comment: is there any other better way? Can you please share the code.

Comment: BTW: Python starts indexes at `0` so you have to use `[3]` to get fouth column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

read1 = csv.reader(open("input1.txt","r"))
read2 = csv.reader(open("input2.txt","r"),delimiter="|")

writter = csv.writer(open("output_file","w"),delimiter="|")

# this is needed because the csv iterator doesn't reset
all_row2 = [x for x in read2]

all_rows = []
for row1 in read1:
    # every row is a list
    # if you want a specific column you can do : if row1[0] in x[4]
    # you get a list of rows   
    all_rows.extend([x for x in all_row2 if row1[0] in x])
# write all at once .. faster
writter.writerows(all_rows)
```

Comment: This is working for only first row. Next matching rows are not writing into file.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indexes

```
    if row1[0] == row2[3]:
```

and this is all your problem

---

**BTW:** next time first use `print()` to see what you have in variables - it helps to see problem.

---

Minimal working code.

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate files - this way everyone can run it.

```
data1 = '''a
b
c'''

data2 = '''1|2|3|a|e|f
1|3|4|b|g|h
3|2|4|c|f|h
d|f|g|i|h|j'''

import csv
import io

read1 = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data1)) # read input file 1
#read1 = csv.reader(open(input1_txt, 'r')) # read input file 1
#write = csv.writer(open(output_file,"w"), delimiter="|", lineterminator="\n")  
 

for row1 in read1:
    read2 = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data2), delimiter="|", lineterminator="\n")
    #read2 = csv.reader(open(input2_file, 'r'), delimiter="|", lineterminator="\n")
    for row2 in read2:
        if row1[0] == row2[3]:
            print('|'.join(row2))
            #write.writerows(row2)
```